# How to implement source for custom Error struct in rust?

Tags: rust

I would like to create a custom error for api with additional properties and struggling to implement `source` which can be any other error. How to do it properly?

[Sandbox](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d3ac8ac824dfc5b7ed67a0c5e9057356).

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyErr {
    pub message: String,
    // todo code and so on
    pub source: Option<&'static dyn std::error::Error>,
}
impl std::fmt::Display for MyErr {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", &self.message)
    }
}
impl std::error::Error for MyErr {
    fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)> {
        self.source
    }
}

fn main() {
       let err1  = MyErr {
        message: "1".to_owned(),
        source: None,
    };
    let err2 =MyErr {
        message: "2".to_owned(),
        source: Some(err1), //expected `&dyn Error`, found `MyErr`
    };

}
```

Comment: You probably want `Option<Box<dyn std::error::Error>>`. I'm assuming you want to take ownership of the inner error. If you *do* really want to borrow it, then you don't want `&'static`, which requires it to basically be a global variable. You want to take a lifetime argument in that case.

Comment: Yes, ownership. But `source` fn for `std::error::Error` trait expects `Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`

Comment: Yes, `source` takes a `&self` and returns a `Option<&(dyn std::error::Error + 'static)>`. You'll return a reference to data owned by `self`, since the (implicit) lifetimes are the same. The `'static` there is a trait bound. It doesn't mean "the reference lives forever", it means roughly "there can't be any hidden references in this data".

Comment: @SilvioMayolo if I change to proposed type I get errors for `fn source` and strange way to pass source error as box `source: Some(Box::new(err1))` which I would like to omit

Comment: Okay, I've tried to write up an answer that hopefully addresses your concerns. See if that helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I indicated in the comments, you're probably looking to *own* rather than *borrow* the error, so you want an `Option<Box<dyn Error>>`

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct MyErr {
  pub message: String,
  pub source: Option<Box<dyn Error>>,
}
```

Now, as you've already noticed, *constructing* an `Option<Box<dyn Error>>` is slightly verbose, so that's why we write our own constructors.

```
impl MyErr {

  fn with_no_source(message: &str) -> MyErr {
    MyErr {
      message: String::from(message),
      source: None,
    }
  }

  fn new<E: Error + 'static>(message: &str, source: E) -> MyErr {
    MyErr {
      message: String::from(message),
      source: Some(Box::new(source)),
    }
  }

}
```

Now `<MyError as Error>::source()` can be implemented simply as

```
self.source.as_deref()
```

[`Option::as_deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) borrows the inside of an `Option`, taking a `Deref` along the way. And `Box` derefs to a reference, which is exactly what we want.

Finally, you can construct these error objects using our provided constructor functions.

```
let err1 = MyErr::with_no_source("1");
let err2 = MyErr::new("2", err1);
```

[Runnable example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3fc5141d57874a20d9f9b93da5375bed)